# Determine the eigenspace and eigenvector of this matrix (just for one eigenvalue)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know there are more eigenvalues but in this example we will only be looking at one to keep it short.

> $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1\\  0 & 1 & 1\\  1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
>
> The characteristic polynomial is
>   $-\lambda^{3}+2\lambda^{2}+\lambda-2=0$
>
> The (single) eigenvalue is $\lambda=1$
>
> Insert $\lambda=1$ here $\begin{pmatrix} 1-\lambda & 0         & 1\\ 
> 0         & 1-\lambda & 1\\  1         & 1         & -\lambda
> \end{pmatrix}$ we get $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\  0 & 0 & 1\\  1 & 1
> & -1 \end{pmatrix}$

We want know the eigenspace:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

$I: z=0$

$II: x+y-z=0 \Leftrightarrow x+y=0 \Leftrightarrow x = -y$

So the eigenspace is $E_{A}(1)= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
-y\\ 
y\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} \mid y \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

And thus an eigenvalue $v_{1}$ would be $v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

Would this eigenvalue $v_{1}$ also be called basis of the eigenspace by the way?

---

I hope everything here is alright? Because that's how I would keep doing my homework.

Comment: 1 is and eigen value and you have found the correct eigenvector for that value.  Your characteristic polynomial is incorrect.  The coefficient of the $\lambda^2$ should be the trace of the matrix.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $-\lambda^3+2\lambda^2+\lambda-2$, and not what you wrote.

Comment: @DougM Corrected, thanks! The rest is fine, also the eigenspace?

Comment: @uniquesolution Corrected, thanks! The rest is fine, also the eigenspace?

Comment: There are 2 more eigen values, and an associated vector with each.

Comment: @DougM I don't care about these because I wanted keep this question as short as possible. Please tell me if everything else is fine :)

Comment: A symmetric matrix always has real eigenvalues.  And as many eigenvectors as number of rows in the matrix.

Comment: You have the used proper thechniques to find the eigenvalue that you have.  And do the same for the other two, and you will be in good shape.

Comment: @DougM Is it correct how I have written the eigenspace?

Comment: Yes, you have correctly identified the eigenspace for that $\lambda$

Comment: Well, other than calling an eigenvector an eigenvalue, it looks OK.